# How to fully uninstall libgdx app on android?

Tags: android, libgdx

Hello I am developing an android game using Libgdx.  However, I have run into a strange problem.  Since I have been testing it for a while now on my Nexus 7 I notice that every single time I "test" or install the application from eclipse onto my device the SD card memory of my Nexus 7 drops by about 0.02 GB.

Even if I unninstall the app from my Nexus 7 the memory will never recover and continually drop.  Why is my device losing SD card space every time I test or install my app?  How can I completely uninstall it?  It's not a very big app either only 5MB.       Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It happens with some apps, some files stay when you uninstall.

check sdcard/Android/data  and sdcard/Android/obb directories. 
and also be sure to check for all folders related to your app in /sdcard/ . Your app might be saving something there.

Comment: Thanks.  I searched through all the folders I could but I could not find the app install location anywhere strangely.  I cleared the cache from the Android recovery mode and it "reset" the SD card memory back to "normal". Nearly 2GB worth which is surprising.  I still don't get why it was doing that every install.